# POSIX regexp for finding everything between wordX and wordY

Tags: regex, posix

I have string as:

```
FOO /some/%string-in.here BAR
```

I would like to get everything between FOO and BAR but **NOT** including `FOO[:space:]` and **NOT** including `[:space:]BAR`

Any ideas it will be appreciate it.

Comment: Use a capture group and then get the value for that group instead of the entire matched text?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using <regex.h> which I'm not quite sure if I can use lookaheads and lookbehinds assertions

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a capturing group?

```
/FOO (.+?) BAR/
```

Comment: POSIX does not support lazy quantifiers

Answer (score 0):

To get everything between FOO and BAR, except any spaces after FOO or before BAR, use this regex for POSIX ERE:

```
FOO[[:space:]]*(.*)[[:space:]]*BAR
```

or for POSIX BRE:

```
FOO[[:space:]]*\(.*\)[[:space:]]*BAR
```

Because POSIX only supports greedy quantifiers, this regex captures everything between FOO and the last occurrence of BAR, in case there is more than one BAR.